Call of Duty cipher: "TheGiant"
I need help figuring out this cipher from Call of Duty Black Ops III. It's been on going for 8 years and no one has been able to solve it. Image

TheGiant
kCmlgFi6GUJNgkNI1Q41fbfyLoCFTCvIqkZiI0KIAXAzP1U1uy1BE4UfPBfpKmmLObjYnQNRBaPtKiVWzc5A4v0w3xle8FOhAGJZ7g4in0wndJxMOvO3dc1M82at2T6935roTqyWDgtGD/hwwRF3oHqFM5Vcw1JtINbsgWRm4o4/quEDkZ7x1B275bX3/Fo1


Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Can you clarify which video game this is from?

This is from Call of Duty Black ops 3, there is a few unsolved cyphers. but many believe solving this one may be a key to solving the "Impossible Easter Egg" for the whole game. Its been on going for many years and no one can solve either or!

Can you edit that into the question, please? We require puzzles to have proper attribution.

is there something in particular about this puzzle that makes it more interesting than the other unsolved ciphers in that game?

Theories, the paper its written on can have meaning or an image, the cipher gives you a key but its not a key or at least the wrong one or a hint towards the key.  Someone dug deep and realized the Os 0s is and Ls were mixed up so they used a tool to clean it up changing the cipher itself which is the text i sent separately from it. Majority believe its two step encrypted which has only happened one other time in game history but it was solved pretty fast. For it to have not been solved in 8 years, and many people linking it be the key for the impossible easter egg once solved.

@thehybrid Who was it who recently did a YouTube video about this cipher?

Partial answer to follow:
Really just a scratchpad, not expecting to see much progress from an 8 y.o. unsolved cipher I guess...

 Here is the binary content from the message in hex form (apply base64decode and then convert to hex):


     9029A58058BA19424D824348D50E357D
     B7F22E80854C2BC8AA46622342880170
     333F5535BB2D4113851F3C17E92A698B
     39B8D89D035105A3ED2A2556CDCE40E2
     FD30DF195EF053A1006259EE0E229F4C
     27749C4C3AF3B775CD4CF366ADD93EBD
     DF9AE84EAC960E0B460FF870C11177A0
     7A8533955CC3526D20D6EC816466E28E
     3FAAE103919EF1D41DBBE5B5F7FC5A35


 ent puzzle_cipher.bin
 Entropy = 6.765309 bits per byte.

 Optimum compression would reduce the size
 of this 144 byte file by 15 percent.

 Chi square distribution for 144 samples is 229.33, and randomly
 would exceed this value 87.44 percent of the times.

 Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 120.0903 (127.5 = random).
 Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.000000000 (error 4.51 percent).
 Serial correlation coefficient is -0.035120 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).

the above command suggests

 that whatever cipher is used is semi to highly secure, due to the higher entropy

and that

 we likely need other information, such as an AES key, possibly found from a prerequisite puzzle or from the image itself such as through steganography

we really need more context, what's the style of crypto puzzles found in the game?
Some miscellaneous observations:

 the hex bytes are exactly 144 bytes, or 12 squared.


 attached here is the BASE32 representation:
 SAU2LACYXIMUETMCINENKDRVPW37ELUAQVGCXSFKIZRCGQUIAFYDGP2VGW5S2QITQUPTYF7JFJUYWONY3COQGUIFUPWSUJKWZXHEBYX5GDPRSXXQKOQQAYSZ5YHCFH2ME52JYTB26O3XLTKM6NTK3WJ6XXPZV2COVSLA4C2GB74HBQIRO6QHVBJTSVOMGUTNEDLOZALEM3RI4P5K4EBZDHXR2QO3XZNV676FUNI=
 entropy of above (ingoring padding) is 4.95567.


The other ciphers in the game used different forms to solving them hell cipher, morse code enigma, substitution cipher, each had a hint within the cipher to help figure out what to use but this one has been impossible

@thehybrid it may even be that in the process of packaging the game assets, they inadvertently made the puzzle unsolvable if my above suspicions are true

Does it have to be encrypted? One would expect similar entropy values from efficiently compressed data, right?

A theory by someone is that everyone thinks its more than what it actually is, meaning it can be easily solved by using a simple method. but even then its been tried by an unknown number of people with no conclusion

@Bass sure, but without knowing the compression scheme it might as well be a cipher in and of itself

ok, from reviewing the context of the ciphers in that game [and area in the game] (which might be helpful information to include in the original question) I would find it more likely that it's a secure cipher such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_and_Halske_T52 Experimenting with https://cryptocellar.org/simula/t52/ I haven't been able to get good results.

if anyone want's to know how I got https://cryptocellar.org/simula/t52/ running, we can talk in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155062/thegiant-puzzle-cipher
